# Parse error: syntax error on '[' when declaring empty array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, server-side

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/cjliu49/public_html/index.php on line 10

on the below code, when I declare '$links = [ ];':

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php");

    $rows = query("SELECT link, description, DATE(timestamp) AS timestamp FROM links WHERE id = ? ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) DESC, timestamp ASC", $_SESSION["id"]);

    $listtitle = query("SELECT title FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    $links = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $links[] = [
        "link" => $rows["link"],
        "description" => $rows["description"],
        "timestamp" => $rows["timestamp"]
        ];
    }

    render("linklist.php", ["title" = $listtitle, "links" => $links]);

?>
```

Am I declaring an empty array variable incorrectly? I also tried '$links[ ] = [ ];' and got the same error.  Or is the error that the server isn't recognizing PHP code?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not running PHP 5.4 which is required ot use that syntax

Comment: ...which means you need change to a web host that lives in the current decade.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, `"As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []."`